# Can't make view from multiple table

Tags: sql, firebird, flamerobin

I'm trying to learn about view in SQL. In my case, i can't execute statement to create view. Here is the statement:

```
CREATE VIEW VTOTALMINUTESEMPLOYEE (EMPL_KODE, EMPL_NAME,DATE_IN, TIME_IN, TIME_OUT, HASIL)
    SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE.EMPL_KODE, 
    EMPLOYEE.EMPL_NAME, 
    ATTANDENCE.DATE_IN, 
    ATTANDENCE.TIME_IN, 
    ATTANDENCE.TIME_OUT,((TIME_OUT-TIME_IN)/60) AS "RESULT" 
    FROM EMPLOYEE 
    JOIN ATTANDENCE 
    ON EMPLOYEE.EMPL_KODE=ATTANDENCE.EMPL_KODE
```

This is the errror code  :

> SQL Message : -104 Invalid token
>
> Engine Code    : 335544569 Engine Message : Dynamic SQL Error SQL
>   error code = -104 Token unknown - line 2, column 9 SELECT

What's wrong with my code ? is there a thing that i missed ? i run the code with flamerobin. please help.

Edit: I get following error:

> -104 Invalid token Engine Code : 335544569 Engine Message : Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 2, column 9
>   SELECT

Comment: What error are you getting?  Are you missing the `as` keyword before the `select` statement?  Not positive if that's required or not.

Comment: This is the errror code  :
SQL Message : -104
Invalid token

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 2, column 9
SELECT

Comment: Try adding `as` in front of `select`?

Comment: I think you have misses "AS" before select. is that the issue?

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tag

Comment: thank you so much for help. I'm trying to add "AS" before "SELECT" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
create view emp_attd_dtls 
as
select 
emp.emp_id,
t.empname,
attend_dateout,
attend_datein,
attend_timein,
attend_timeout
from employee emp
inner join emp_attend t on emp.emp_id =t.emp_id
```